# Rails : Why my url is not correct when clicking on two static pages?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hyperlink

I am new to Ruby On Rails. I am building a website with Rails.

I've created static pages : Faq, Mentions, Contact and CGU. 
Here is the code :

```
   <li><%= link_to "Nous contacter", 'static_pages/contact' %></li>
   <li><%= link_to "FAQ", 'static_pages/faq' %></li>
   <li><%= link_to "CGU/CGV", 'static_pages/cgu' %></li>
   <li><%= link_to "Mentions Légales", 'static_pages/mentions' %></li>
```

I put this page on the footer. Here is the screen shot : [image]

I can access all my static when typing the entire url :

- http://localhost:3000/static_pages/faq
- http://localhost:3000/static_pages/mentions
- http://localhost:3000/static_pages/contact

The problem appears when i click on the in the footer :

1. on one static page ( example : Nous Contacter ) => my url is http://localhost:3000/static_pages/contact
2. Then i click one the another static page link ( such as Faq) : 
   my url is then http://localhost:3000/static_pages/static_pages/faq which is not correct.

I don't understand why i Rails add static_pages twice in the url ?

Comment: Prepend a slash at your addresses and repeat the test. Like in    <li><%= link_to "FAQ", '/static_pages/faq' %></li>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
 <li><%= link_to "Nous contacter", '/static_pages/contact' %></li>
 <li><%= link_to "FAQ", '/static_pages/faq' %></li>
 <li><%= link_to "CGU/CGV", '/static_pages/cgu' %></li>
 <li><%= link_to "Mentions Légales", '/static_pages/mentions' %></li>
```